# Multiple s3-buckets in aws amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

so i wanted my react-amplify application to access multiple s3 buckets. I followed [this](https://medium.com/dnx-labs/using-multiple-buckets-aws-amplify-66083d7a4301) tutorial and achieved it. it was pretty straightforward. the Storage.get() and Storage.put() code looks something like this respectively

```
Storage.get('/path/to/file', {bucket: 'bucketname'})
Storage.put('/path', 'object',{bucket: 'bucketname'}
```

this code works fine. but when I try to get or put operation... I get s3-access denied error as my bucket is private.

I tried to add s3fullaccess permission to the backend role that is used by my amplify app... but still, I have no success. I am not sure what else would help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to access the s3 buckets....

edit the authenticated or the unauthenticated role of your identity pool using IAM Roles

edit the pre existing policies auto generated by AWS Amplify and add new new bucket arn.

refer first half of this blog: https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-from-react-app-using-aws-amplify-b286dbad2dd7

Comment: One more thing to add `Storage.put` will throw Access Denied error, even though editing the identity pool, using `Storage.vault.put` solve the issue.